# "uncaught TypeError: Object is not a function" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I am having trouble understanding why this is not working. I have two fields on my form and when I click a button another text field value is changed to that if the function. How can I get this to work?

```
function calculate()
{
    var odometerStart = parseFloat (document.getElementById('odometerStart').value);
    var odometerEnd = parseFloat(document.getElementById('odometerEnd').value);
    var distance = document.getElementById('distance');
    var amount = document.getElementById('amount');

    distance.value = odometerEnd - odometerStart;       
}

var val = $("#taskentry").validate({
    rules: {
        tripDate: {required: true}
        tripContact: {required: true}
        odometerStart: {required: true}     
    }
});


Odometer: Start <input type="number" name="odometer[Start]" id="odometerStart" min="0" max="999999" placeholder="0" class="required"/><br/>
Odometer: End <input type="number" name="odometer[End]" id="odometerEnd" min="0" max="999999" placeholder="999999" class="required"/><br/>
Comments <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="2" cols="2"></textarea><br/>
Distance <input type="text" name="distance" id="distance" value="" placeholder="0.00"/><br/>
<input type="button" name="calculate" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate()"/>
```

I am debuging this in Google Chrome using the developer tools and am getting the error "uncaught TypeError: Object is not a function" at the point where the calculate button is.

Comment: Your code works. Here's a fiddle to prove it: nothing on JSLint and no exceptions returned -- http://jsfiddle.net/YahzF/

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Perhaps you need commas:

```
var val = $("#taskentry").validate({
    rules: {
        tripDate: {required: true},
        tripContact: {required: true},
        odometerStart: {required: true}     
    }
});
```

Comment: He was saying you had a syntax error. Commas separate properties of an object, so keep those commas there.

Comment: why is this marked as the correct answer if the asker says it didn't work?

Answer (score 54):

Sorry for the huge gap between your question and my answer :)
I just got the same problem and found the reason - browser automatically populates objects based on ID attributes of the html tags in the page.
Simple test

```
<div id='test'>Just testing</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
alert(test.innerHTML);
</script>
```

In your case you had an element with id='calculate', rename it or rename the function you are using for calculations.

Comment: Had the same issue and this was my fix

Comment: I didn't know about this browser behaviour, until just now! I wouldn't need a lot of document.getElementById() if I knew about this.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I have

`<input type="button" class="button" id="register" title="register" value="Sign Up!" onclick="register()" />`

and get the same warning when I call the javascript function `register()`, I guess it is conflicted with `id` or `title` attributes in the `input` tag, so I just alter this function into another name such as `signup()` and it works around.

I hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem with a function I created, working perfectly with Firefox and giving this error with Chrome and Safari. The solution: change the name of the function. The original name was `expand(target)`, replaced by expand_compress(target). And it worked. I suppose that the function `expand()` is existing somewhere else than in Firefox

Comment: You might want to take note of [Cheery's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8968495/119477) as to why that change matters. You probably had an html tag that had an id of "expand"