# Onclick event not firing (this is so basic, am i going insane?)

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“uncaught TypeError: Object is not a function” in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773775/uncaught-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-in-javascript)

my full js file is this:

```
function addInning() {
    alert("hello");
}
```

my html file has the element
    `<input name="addInning" type="button" value="Add Inning" id="addInning" onclick="addInning();">`

and the code will not execute. for the life of me i cannot figure out why, as this is just about the simplest thing possible. the error from chrome is "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function". I searched on stackoverflow and the solutions posted have not been helpful. i feel like i'm losing my mind.

full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/BUsPC/

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of javascript and DOM.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Nrnsc/. Is the function in the head of your document?

Comment: I guess you are not referencing your JS file in the html markup page

Comment: Any javascript errors popup when you click the button?

Comment: the head of the document has a reference to js/scripts.js, which is where the function is. adding "addInning();" to the top of the js file fires the popup when the page loads without a problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Dkrqn/ Just check this,

Comment: If you are referencing a file, open your browsers Developer Tools and check for JS errors, might not be linking it right.

Comment: Do you have other JavaScript that might be interfering with the click event on that element?

Comment: Your code is correct (tested in Chrome and Firefox). Where do you put your js code? It needs to be before your button declaration.

Comment: full code here http://jsfiddle.net/BUsPC/ (though i removed the header line referencing the scripts.js file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the name and id from "addInning" to something else.  This worked for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addInning()
    {
        alert("hello");
    }

</script>
<input name="addInning2" type="button" value="Add Inning" id="addInning2" onclick="addInning();">
```

Comment: wow that worked....why? this is my normal naming convention for functions and ids, but i've never seen this problem before? thanks!!

Comment: Alex, your question is a duplicate of another already [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773775/uncaught-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-in-javascript), which provides more detail about what's going on.

Comment: did some further quick tests to see if it was only the id or the element name...neither can have the same name as the javascript function (at least in this situation).

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that in `onclick="addInning();"`, `addInning` is referring to the `input` element because that's the value set for its `name` and `id` attributes. This behavior seems to be prompted only when the `input` tag is a child of a `form` element.

This [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fanet/6/) highlights that behavior.

To solve your problem, either change the name of **both** the `input`'s `id` and `name`, or the name of `addInning`. Also, you could explicitly refer to the global function like this:

```
onclick="window.addInning();"
```

Take a look at your working [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BUsPC/33/) using the latter option. Be careful with JSFiddle because it wraps all JS in an `window.onload` event by default. You could keep the default behavior by defining `addInning` like so:

```
window.addInning = function () {
    alert("hello");
}​;​
```

I learnt something new!

Comment: you're right, that definitely executes in fiddle...but then what's the difference between that and the html in my fiddle? how do i define addInning first?

Comment: The script does not have to be defined before the element appears.  It only has to be there before the element is clicked.  The code in the `onclick` attribute isn't run (meaning, JS doesn't look for the `addInning` function) until the element is clicked.  The code works fine for me whether the script comes before or after.

Comment: @cHao Really? Why doesn't [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fanet/1/) work then?

Comment: @depot: You're defining the function with `function addInning() {...}` (making it local) rather than `addInning = function() {...}`.   [Works fine with the declaration fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/fanet/2/).

Comment: @cHao I did some more research and that's not the issue. Checkout the updated post.

Comment: @Alex My initial response was wrong. Checkout the updated post!

Comment: @depot: Yeah, i was noticing that when i tried the fiddle from the OP.  Seems the form manages to get into the scope chain.  Not sure about where it's specified that that should happen, but eh.  If the onclick uses `window.addInning()` rather than just `addInning`, it should work.

Comment: @depot: For reference... see http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#event-handlers , particularly #6 under that section... "Lexical Environment *Scope*".  If an element has a form as a parent, that form is specified to become part of the event handler's scope.

Comment: @cHao Thanks for the link. Interesting!

Answer (score 0):

Since its a function, try returning something:

```
function addInning() {
   alert("hello");
   return true;  // or return false; to prevent the click
}
```

Comment: No, `false` is the only return value that matters for event handlers.  Returning anything else, including nothing, makes no difference.

Comment: But the OP used `addInning()` as the event handler for the `onclick` event.