# JS: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function (onclick)

Tags: javascript, html

**Edit:** [Here's a JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XpmZG/)

**Edit2:** The error is on this line: `<input type="button" value="totalbandwidthresult" onclick="javascript:totalbandwidth();">`

Trying to have a button perform a calculation. The required variables are below, as well as the HTML where

I am getting an error onclick: `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function index.html:71
onclick`

Here is my Javascript

```
function totalbandwidth() {  
    var fps=Number(document.calculator.fps.value);  
    var bitrate=Number(document.calculator.bitrate.value);  
    var numberofcameras = Number(document.calculator.numberofcameras.value); 
    var encoding = document.calculator.encoding.value; 
    if (encoding = "mjpeg")
    {
        storage = bitrate*fps;
    }
    else
    {
        storage = bitrate;
    }

    totalbandwidth = (numberofcameras * storage) / 1000;
    document.calculator.totalbandwidthresult.value = totalbandwidth;  
}
```

The HTML:

```
<form name="calculator" class="formtable">  
<div class="formrow"><label for="rcname">RC Name</label> <input type="text" name="rcname"></div>  
<div class="formrow"><label for="fps">FPS</label> <input type="text" name="fps">  </div>  
<div class="formrow"><label for="bitrate">Bitrate</label> <input type="text" name="bitrate">  </div>  
<div class="formrow"><label for="numberofcameras">Number of Cameras</label> <input type="text" name="numberofcameras"> </div>   
<div class="formrow"><label for="encoding">Encoding</label> <select name="encoding" id="encodingoptions">
  <option value="h264">H.264</option>
  <option value="mjpeg">MJPEG</option>
  <option value="mpeg4">MPEG4</option>
</select></div>  
Total Storage: <input type="text" name="totalstorage">   
Total Bandwidth: <input type="text" name="totalbandwidth">   
<input type="button" value="totalbandwidthresult" onclick="javascript:totalbandwidth();">
```

Basically - it seems that there may be something wrong with the syntax I used in the JS - but I'm not sure.

Comment: Please make a JSFiddle link.

Comment: @coramba just added jsFiddle

Comment: @rid - sorry, line 71 is the onclick button with value totalbandwidthresult

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Please change only the name of the function; no other change is required

```
<script>
    function totalbandwidthresult() {
        alert("fdf");
        var fps = Number(document.calculator.fps.value);
        var bitrate = Number(document.calculator.bitrate.value);
        var numberofcameras = Number(document.calculator.numberofcameras.value);
        var encoding = document.calculator.encoding.value;
        if (encoding = "mjpeg") {
            storage = bitrate * fps;
        } else {
            storage = bitrate;
        }

        totalbandwidth = (numberofcameras * storage) / 1000;
        alert(totalbandwidth);
        document.calculator.totalbandwidthresult.value = totalbandwidth;
    }
</script>

<form name="calculator" class="formtable">
    <div class="formrow">
        <label for="rcname">RC Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="rcname">
    </div>
    <div class="formrow">
        <label for="fps">FPS</label>
        <input type="text" name="fps">
    </div>
    <div class="formrow">
        <label for="bitrate">Bitrate</label>
        <input type="text" name="bitrate">
    </div>
    <div class="formrow">
        <label for="numberofcameras">Number of Cameras</label>
        <input type="text" name="numberofcameras">
    </div>
    <div class="formrow">
        <label for="encoding">Encoding</label>
        <select name="encoding" id="encodingoptions">
            <option value="h264">H.264</option>
            <option value="mjpeg">MJPEG</option>
            <option value="mpeg4">MPEG4</option>
        </select>
    </div>Total Storage:
    <input type="text" name="totalstorage">Total Bandwidth:
    <input type="text" name="totalbandwidth">
    <input type="button" value="totalbandwidthresult" onclick="totalbandwidthresult();">
</form>
```

Comment: why by changing the name fixed the problem?

Comment: @StevenHernandez - they conflicted. Once the names were changed the conflict was resolved.

Comment: yes I see your point. thanks! I suppose JS is very delicate about naming conventions so we have to try to make every name unique.

Comment: totalbandwidthresult function name is conflicted so we need to change function name.

Comment: Gah I just had the same problem, been trying to debug it for hours, glad this question existed thank you.

Answer (score 26):

Since the behavior is kind of strange, I have done some testing on the behavior, and here's my result:

### TL;DR

If you are:

- **In a `form`**, and
- uses `onclick="xxx()"` on an element
- **don't** add `id="xxx"` or `name="xxx"` to that element

  - (e.g. **<form><button id="totalbandwidth" onclick="totalbandwidth()">BAD</button></form>** )

---

Here's are some test and their result:

#### Control sample *(can successfully call function)*

```js
function totalbandwidth(){ alert("Total Bandwidth > 9000Mbps"); }
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;">
  <button onclick="totalbandwidth()">SUCCESS</button>
</form>
```

#### Add id to button *(failed to call function)*

```js
function totalbandwidth(){ alert("Total Bandwidth > 9000Mbps"); }
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;">
  <button id="totalbandwidth" onclick="totalbandwidth()">FAILED</button>
</form>
```

#### Add name to button *(failed to call function)*

```js
function totalbandwidth(){ alert("Total Bandwidth > 9000Mbps"); }
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;">
  <button name="totalbandwidth" onclick="totalbandwidth()">FAILED</button>
</form>
```

#### Add value to button *(can successfully call function)*

```js
function totalbandwidth(){ alert("Total Bandwidth > 9000Mbps"); }
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;">
  <input type="button" value="totalbandwidth" onclick="totalbandwidth()" />SUCCESS
</form>
```

#### Add id to button, but not in a form *(can successfully call function)*

```js
function totalbandwidth(){ alert("Total Bandwidth > 9000Mbps"); }
```

```html
<button id="totalbandwidth" onclick="totalbandwidth()">SUCCESS</button>
```

#### Add id to another element inside the form *(can successfully call function)*

```js
function totalbandwidth(){ alert("The answer is no, the span will not affect button"); }
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;">
<span name="totalbandwidth" >Will this span affect button? </span>
<button onclick="totalbandwidth()">SUCCESS</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The reason is that inside a HTML form and just inside a HTML form, the onclick() JavaScript block will get a scope injected which holds all other input elements of the form. So the element with the name "xxx" shadows the global function with the name "xxx". See also https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/javascript-variables-inside-form-elements-event-attributes-aa945388a47d

Comment: oh man the element name + function name conflict got me a few times

Comment: Your advice don't add id or name resolved my issue.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to figure it out by following the answer in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8968495/1543447

Basically, I renamed all values, function names, and element names to different values so they wouldn't conflict - and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

This Kind of Problem happens if you have a capital letter in your Function so change it to a small letter words. It will work  or else make the name of the Function short