# Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.addHandleSubmit

Tags: javascript, axios

Not sure I understand why is this error showing. 
The error seems to disappear when commenting out `getCityData("username", where)`  in HandleSubmit.js.  I have checked related answers to this but doesn't seem to be related.

[JS: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function (onclick)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620620/js-uncaught-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-onclick)

Thanks in advance

Error

```
HandleSubmit.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.addHandleSubmit (HandleSubmit.js:16)
```

getData.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

 async function getCityData(username, city) {
    const url=  "http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=",
    completeURL = `${url}${city}&username=${username}`
    console.log(completeURL)

    try {
        let data = await axios.get(completeURL).then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(response.status);
            console.log(response.statusText);
            console.log(response.headers);
            console.log(response.config);
            data = response;
          });
          return data;

    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log("error", error);
      }



}

export default  {
    getCityData
}
```

HandleSubmit.js

```
import getCityData from "./getData"



function addHandleSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const where = document.getElementById("where").value
    const when = document.getElementById("when").value

    // if (where=='' || when=='') {
    //     alert('Please make sure you have add a Where and When')
    // }
    console.log(`To ${where} departing ${when}`)


   getCityData("username", where)




}
export default {
    addHandleSubmit
}
```

index.js

```
import "./styles/styles.scss";
import addHandle from "./js/HandleSubmit";
import getCityData from "./js/getData";


document.getElementById("add-trip").addEventListener('click', addHandle.addHandleSubmit)

export {
    addHandle,
    getCityData

}
```

index.html

```
                 <div class="add-trip-form">
                        <form>
                            <label for="where"> where</label>
                            <input type="text" id="where"> 
                            <label for="when"> When</label>
                            <input type="date" id="when">
                            <button class="add-trip-class" id="add-trip"> Add Trip</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Comment: You don't have any exports in `HandleSubmit.js`.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, just edited the question. I had it in the original code, missed adding it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HandleSubmit.js, you should import like this:

```
import { getCityData } from "./getData"
```

Otherwise you would be importing `getCityData` as an Object, and not like a function. That's why you get that error

Comment: Hi @hans, this seemed to fixed the issue when also editing HandleSubmit.js export.
From  export default {
    addHandleSubmit
}

to export  {
    addHandleSubmit
}

Thanks!